# How to extract a required text

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have a column which contains values of dates and text with certain file extensions. I split up the file names to 3 different columns, one of them has these dates and text.

Example: 13.04.26.xls(date) or v1.xls(text)

I want a formula to extract 13.04.26 and v1. 
I tried using "Right" formula but the number count varies as I have two different kinds of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `13.04.26.xls` in cell A1 and you want to get correct result to cell B2 just put the following formula in B1:

```
=MID(A1,1,SEARCH(".xls",A1)-1)
```

Comment: in C1 add this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","-")` to get data syntax in C1. You need to copy-paste value of C1 result, convert it with `text to columns` and finally you have data type value. It could be possibly easier with UDF ;)

Comment: you mean using macro? i am trying to write a macro to convert to a date

Comment: `=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","-"))`

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan, please add it as an answer.

Comment: KazJaw answered your question, I just commented on the follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".xls",A1)-1),".","-")
```